# Как следать закругленый BG как на картинке?

Tags: css3, html5

Как следать закругленый BG как на картинке?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А дальше медиа запросы и.т.д

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.sk {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

ul a {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 0;
}

hr {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="svg">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 297 210" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient834" x1="148.92262" x2="148.92262" y1="-55.667683" y2="298.87399" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <stop stop-color="#ccc" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="#ccc" stop-opacity="0" offset="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <g transform="translate(0,-87)">
  <path d="m0 106.50001c123.16407-31.75567 211.56904-17.775673 297.08929 0v190.5h-297.08929z" fill="url(#linearGradient834)"/>
 </g>
</svg>

  </div>
  <div class="sk">
    <h2>Каталог велосипедов</h2>
    <hr>
    <ul>
      <a href="#">item1</a>
      <a href="#">item2</a>
      <a href="#">item3</a>
      <a href="#">item4</a>
      <a href="#">item5</a>
      <a href="#">item6</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#oval {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(193, 193, 193, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(193, 193, 193, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(193, 193, 193, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c1c1c1', endColorstr='#00ffffff', GradientType=0);
  border-radius: 40% 40% 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="oval"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать поиграться border-radius, значения зависят от размеров вашего блока. Ниже пример.

```css
.block-gray{
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f0f0f0, white);
  border-radius:450px 450px 0 0 / 50px 50px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-gray"></div>
```

Если нужно чтобы была острота в углах, как вариант - блок сделать больше и лишнее обрезать. Пример:

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.block-gray{
  width: 110%;
  margin-left:-5%;
  height: 300px;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f0f0f0, white);
  border-radius:450px 450px 0 0 / 120px 120px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block-gray"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: кстати если развернуть на весь экран то получается порнуха

Comment: значения border-radius нужно подбирать по факту, т.к. в зависимости от размеров блока по разному выглядит.